# How to close cmd.exe window while its being ran as a process in a background worker C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, process, backgroundworker

I am very new to C# and trying to understand background workers.

Currently when I run this code it will stop redirecting and reading the output from the command prompt after the StopButton has been clicked and leaves the "cancelled" message behind, but then does nothing afterwards. I currently may be implementing this all wrong, but I have the e.Cancel set by clicking the stop button that calls CancelAsync(), which turns CancellationPending = true. Anyone have any ideas how I should go about this?

Thanks so much!!
I appreciate the help!

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new   
        RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

    }

    private void StopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation == true)
        {
            bw.CancelAsync();
            bw.Dispose();

            Invoke(new ToDoDelegate(() => this.textBox2.Text += Environment.NewLine + "Cancelled " + Environment.NewLine));
        }
    }

    private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if(bw.IsBusy != true)
            {
                bw.RunWorkerAsync();
                Invoke(new ToDoDelegate(() => this.textBox2.Text += "Starting Download " + Environment.NewLine));
            }

    }

    public bool DoSVNCheckout(String KeyUrl, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        SVNProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {

                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C plink download files using svn"
                Verb = "runas",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
            }
        };

        SVNProcess.Start();
        while(!SVNProcess.StandardOutput.EndOfStream & bw.CancellationPending == false)
        {
            string output = SVNProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Invoke(new ToDoDelegate(() => this.textBox2.Text += output));
        }
        while (!SVNProcess.StandardError.EndOfStream & bw.CancellationPending == false)
        {
            string Erroutput = SVNProcess.StandardError.ReadLine();
            Invoke(new ToDoDelegate(() => this.textBox2.Text += Erroutput));
        }
        if(SVNProcess.StandardError.EndOfStream & bw.CancellationPending == false)
        {
            string Erroutput = SVNProcess.StandardError.ReadLine();
            Invoke(new ToDoDelegate(() => this.textBox2.Text += Erroutput));
        }

        //if I manually close the cmd.exe window by clicking X
        //in the top right corner the program runs correctly
        //at these lines of code right here

        if(bw.CancellationPending == true)
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private delegate void ToDoDelegate();
    private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;


            if(bw.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }
            e.Cancel = DoSVNCheckout(URL, e);

    }
    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if ((e.Cancelled == true))
        {
            this.textBox2.Text = "Canceled!";
        }
        else{
            this.textBox2.Text = "Done!";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this is asynchronous.  This is just multithreading.  Take a look at [CancellationTokenSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Are you saying that I should not use the command "CancelAsync()"? This command does seem to stop the current operation, but does nothing afterwards.

Comment: I'm saying consider using the CancellationTokenSource and CancellationToken.  That's exactly what it is designed for.

Comment: @Felix: perhaps you could elaborate. IME, `CancellationToken` is useful if one has a CPU-bound operation where it's possible to periodically check for cancellation (e.g. call `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`) in a reliable way. But in this case, the current process is simply waiting on the external one it started; IMHO, setting up some kind of loop just to poll the token seems less useful than e.g. creating a `TaskCompletionSource` to represent a user's asynchronous input (see my proposed answer).

Comment: @Felix: But if you know of a better way, where the `CancellationToken` can be integrated in a more direct, more clean fashion, I encourage you to provide those details, as they would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of problems with the code you've written. The two primary issues, in my opinion are:

1. First and foremost, you seem to be confusing the `BackgroundWorker` operation with the separately-running process you've started. The two are not by any means the same, or even related to each other. Cancelling the `BackgroundWorker` won't have any direct effect on the process you start. Your question is not clear on what the actual desired behavior is here, but you don't do anything to actually terminate the external process. At best, if you weren't blocking the `DoWork` method waiting for the process to produce output, you'd abandon the process. As it is, without terminating the process, your `DoWork` can never get to a point where it notices you've tried to cancel it, because it's stuck on a `ReadLine()` call.
2. You are consuming the `StandardOutput` and `StandardError` streams in serial fashion, i.e. one after the other. The documentation clearly warns against this, as this is a very reliable way to deadlock your code. The buffers for each stream are relatively small, and the entire external process will hang if it tries to write to one of these streams when the buffer is full. This will in turn cause no more output to be written to any of the streams. In your code example, if the `StandardError` stream buffer gets full before you have been able to completely read the `StandardOutput` stream, the external process will hang and your own process will as well.

Another minor issue is that you don't take advantage of the `BackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged` event, which you could have used to pass text you've read from the output and error strings back to the UI thread where you could add that text to your text box. The use of `Control.Invoke()` here isn't strictly necessary, and fails to fully take advantage of the features in `BackgroundWorker`.

There are ways to modify the code you've written, so that you can still use `BackgroundWorker` and achieve your goal. One obvious improvement that you could make would be to store the `Process` object reference in an instance field, so that it's accessible by the `StopButton_Click()` method. In that method, you could call the `Process.Kill()` method to actually terminate the process.

But even so, you would need to fix the deadlock-prone implementation you've got now. This can be done in a variety of ways: use the `Process.OutputDataReceived` and `Process.ErrorDataReceived` events; create a second `BackgroundWorker` task to process one of the streams; use the `Task`-based idioms to read the streams.

The last option there would be my preference. The second option needlessly creates long-running threads, while the event-based pattern (the first option) is awkward to use (and is line-based, so has limited value when dealing with processes that write partial lines during the course of their operation). But if you're going to use the `Task`-based idioms for reading the streams, it seems to me you should upgrade the entire implementation to do so.

`BackgroundWorker` is still a viable class to use if one wants to, but the new `Task` features in conjunction with the `async`/`await` keywords offer what is IMHO a much easier and cleaner way to handle asynchronous operations. One of the biggest advantages is that it doesn't rely on explicitly used threads (e.g. running the `DoWork` event handler in a thread pool thread). Asynchronous I/O operations such as what makes up the entirety of your scenario here, are handled implicitly via the API, allowing all of the code you write to be executed in the UI thread where you want it.

Here is a version of your example that does just this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _cancelTask;

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Enabled = false;
        button2.Enabled = true;
        _cancelTask = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        try
        {
            await RunProcess();
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The operation was cancelled");
        }
        finally
        {
            _cancelTask = null;
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _cancelTask.SetCanceled();
    }

    private async Task RunProcess()
    {
        Process process = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C pause",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
            }
        };

        process.Start();

        Task readerTasks = Task.WhenAll(
            ConsumeReader(process.StandardError),
            ConsumeReader(process.StandardOutput));

        Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(readerTasks, _cancelTask.Task);

        if (completedTask == _cancelTask.Task)
        {
            process.Kill();
            await readerTasks;
            throw new TaskCanceledException(_cancelTask.Task);
        }
    }

    private async Task ConsumeReader(TextReader reader)
    {
        char[] text = new char[512];
        int cch;

        while ((cch = await reader.ReadAsync(text, 0, text.Length)) > 0)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(new string(text, 0, cch));
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. First, as you can see, there is no longer a need for `BackgroundWorker` at all. The `async`/`await` pattern implicitly does all of the same work that `BackgroundWorker` would have for you, but without all the extra boilerplate code required to set it up and manage it.
2. There is a new instance field, `_cancelTask`, which represents a simple `Task` object that can be completed. It's only ever completed by being cancelled, in this case, but that's not strictly required…you'll note that the `await` statement that monitors the task completion doesn't actually care how the task ended. Just that it did. In more complex scenarios, one might actually want to use the `Result` for such a `Task` object, calling `SetResult()` to complete the task with a value, and using `SetCanceled()` for actually cancelling the operation being represented. It all depends on the specific context.
3. The `button1_Click()` method (equivalent to your `Submit_Click()` method) is written as if everything happens synchronously. Through the "magic" of the `await` statement, the method actually executes in two parts. When you click the button, everything up to the `await` statement executes; at the `await`, once the `RunProcess()` method has returned, the `button1_Click()` method returns. It will resume execution later, when the `Task` object returned by `RunProcess()` completes, which in turn will happen when that method reaches its end (i.e. *not* the first time it returns).
4. In the `button1_Click()` method, the UI is updated to reflect the current state of operation: the start button is disabled and the cancel button is enabled. Before returning, the buttons are returned to their original state.
5. The `button1_Click()` method is also where the `_cancelTask` object is created and later discarded. The `await RunProcess()` statement will see a `TaskCanceledException` if the `RunProcess()` throws it; this is used to present the user with the `MessageBox` reporting that the operation had been cancelled. You can of course respond to an exception like this however you see fit.
6. In this way, the `button2_Click()` method (equivalent to your `StopButton_Click()` method) only has to set the `_cancelTask` object to a completed state, in this case by calling `SetCanceled()`.
7. The `RunProcess()` method is where the main handling of the process occurs. It starts the process, then waits for the relevant tasks to complete. The two tasks representing the output and error streams are wrapping in a call to `Task.WhenAll()`. This creates a new `Task` object that will complete only when all of the wrapped tasks are completed. Then the method waits via `Task.WhenAny()` for that wrapper task and the `_cancelTask` object. If *either* completes, the method will complete execution. If the completed task was the `_cancelTask` object, the method does so by killing the process that was started (interrupting it in the middle of whatever it was doing), waiting for the processs to actually exit (which can be observed by the completion of the wrapper task…these complete when the end of both the output and the error streams is reached, which in turn happens when the process has exited), and then throwing the `TaskCanceledException`.
8. The `ConsumeReader()` method is a helper method that simple reads text from the given `TextReader` object, and appends the output to the text box. It uses `TextReader.ReadAsync()`; this type of method can also be written using `TextReader.ReadLineAsync()`, but in that case you will only see output at the end of each line. Using `ReadAsync()` ensures that output is retrieved as soon as it's available, without waiting for newline characters.
9. Note that the `RunProcess()` and `ConsumeReader()` methods are also `async`, and also have `await` statements in them. As with `button1_Click()`, these methods initially return from executing upon reaching the `await` statement, resuming execution later when the awaited `Task` completes. In the `ConsumeReader()` example, you'll also notice that `await` unpacks the `int` value that is the `Result` property value of the `Task<int>` it was waiting on. The `await` statement forms an expression that evaluates to the waited `Task`'s `Result` value.
10. A very important characteristic of the use of `await` in each of these cases is that the framework resumes execution of the method *on the UI thread*. This is why the `button1_Click()` method can still access the UI objects `button1` and `button2` after the `await`, and why `ConsumeReader()` can access the `textBox1` object for the purpose of appending text each time some is returned by the `ReadAsync()` method.

I realize the above might be a lot to digest. Especially when most of it relates to the complete change from the use of `BackgroundWorker` to the `Task`-based API, rather than addressing the main two issues I mentioned at the outset. But I hope you can see how those issues are implicitly addressed by these changes, as well as how other requirements of the code are met in a simpler, easier-to-read fashion by using the modern `async`/`await` pattern.

For completeness, here is the Designer-generated code that goes along with the above `Form1` class:

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "Start";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Enabled = false;
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(93, 12);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button2.Text = "Stop";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this.textBox1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 42);
        this.textBox1.Multiline = true;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
        this.textBox1.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Vertical;
        this.textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(488, 258);
        this.textBox1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(513, 312);
        this.Controls.Add(this.textBox1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation! I am going to rework my code around and will respond back with some hopefully working code!

Comment: I have a follow up question that can be view here dealing with cancelling the task while its running: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903661/how-to-cancel-a-async-task-that-starts-a-process-in-c

Comment: @Ross: `_cancelTask.SetCanceled()` doesn't directly stop the external process at all. It's simply a signal to _your_ code, allowing the call to `WhenAny()` to complete. When this happens, the call to `Process.Kill()` does terminate the process at that time. I.e. effectively it is doing what you want. It's just important to understand what part of the code is doing what. Do note that killing the process isn't the same as gracefully interrupting an operation, assuming the external program even has a way to do that: you're just stopping it outright; that could leave things in an incomplete state.